# Why is the footer and header of jQuery Mobile not being displayed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The fiddle contains all the necessary information.

I simply added the header source and footer source into my source from jQuery Mobile website

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6b2ta2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">  </script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js">  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using header and footer outside of the pages (external), you need to initialize the widgets (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-external/):

```
$(function(){
    $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ly6b2ta2/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

I am just wondering, in the original fiddle, I enabled swiping left and swiping right.  It stops working after swiping about ten times.  Do you see any solution to solve that issue?  Do you see anything wrong in my code where it deals with swiping left and right?

Comment: @KershawRocks, the code looks OK to me, and for me the swipe keeps working (in Chrome). Does this issue happen on a particular browser/device, or all the time?

Comment: On my Android phone, I have to swipe multiple times to let the page swipe once. Other applications such as facebook swipe very easily.